# Nodes - Choose the Layer to appear JavaFX2

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I want to be able to choose the layer that the Nodes appear and change it throughout the course of the program.

I know that the last added Nodes appear on the top of the previous one.

In swing, I use JLayeredPane and its method setLayout(JComponent, integer). The higher the int, the higher level the component appears on screen.

Is there something similar?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you can play with the z-order indices of child nodes by combinations of

```
Node node = pane.getChildren().get(index);
Node node = pane.getChildren().remove(index);
pane.getChildren().add(newIndex, node);
```

Comment: I looked up the z-order you noticed and found the toFront() and toBack methods. So, along with your suggestion, I think I am ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A layout has been done to do this job : [StackPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html).

The JavaFX tutorial has a [chapter dedicated to it](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm#sthref10).

The different pane are stacked but if the opacity is not set to 100 %, they are all visible.