# JavaFx StackPane in SceneBuilder, how to make only front pane visible without setting disabling visibility of others?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, scenebuilder

Related question: [Nodes - Choose the Layer to appear JavaFX2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709016/nodes-choose-the-layer-to-appear-javafx2/17511649#17511649)

I'm using JavaFx 8 with SceneBuilder 2. I have a number of panes as children of a StackPane and I would like to make only the front Node visible. I need to do this without disabling visibility of the other children, and I've tried to do this using the opacity setting seen below (ignore the fact that visibility is disabled):

[image: Opacity already set]

Without disabling the visiblity of the other child nodes, the children are always drawn over each other, even when using different blend modes (SRC_OVER & SRC_ATOP), as seen below:

[image]

The reason I would like to avoid setting visibility to false of the child elements is that I want to animate a transition between the panes, in which one pane needs to be draw over the top of the other.

I must be missing something obvious here, but I can't see what it is?

Comment: You can add a `background color` to the panes which would block visibility to other panes. Moreover, setting visibility doesn't sound a bad option as well. You can always change the visibility while transitioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to set the background colour of the panes. Opacity has no effect without first setting a background colour.

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the visibility to false.
To do that, call `setVisible(false)` on the node you'd like to render invisible in the StackPane.

See [Node::setVisible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setVisible-boolean-)